# Automatically close JqueryDialog

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, jqgrid

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  
    onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
    onselectedindexchanging="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanging">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField HeaderText="Show" SelectText="ShowMessage" 
            ShowSelectButton="True" />
    </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>

<div id="content"><div>

protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
{   
        string html = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            html += "<div style='display:none' id='" + i + "'>" + GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Text + "</div>";
            GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Attributes.Add("onclick", "$('#" + i + "').dialog()");
        }
        content.InnerHtml = html;  
}
```

show dialog onclick cells[0] and automatically close dialog? why?

Answer (score 0):

My WebForms is somewhat rusty but if that `GridView1_SelectedIndexChanging` is going to be called each time you change to another row the code will be recreating the dialog bit each time.  That could be why it disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you're selecting another row in your grid, the `GridView1_SelectedIndexChanging` event on server needs to be fired, for that a complete `PostBack` needs to occur in order to get the changed data.

Whenever, a `PostBack` occurs, all your things done using JavaScript are gone and need to be initialize once again when the page is loaded again.

Consider a `PostBack` like a new page request to the server.

You may consider using **ASP.NET AJAX** and put your `DataGrid` in an `UpdatePanel` to avoid full page `PostBack` but only the DataGrid section.